# Expo av doesn't pause on navigation.goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation, expo-av

I have 3 screens, `A`, `B` and `C`. On B, I have an audio autoplaying. I have a Header which allows me to go forward to C or backward to A.

I have tried the code below. While the sound does stop when going B->C, when I go B->A it doesn't pause no matter what I tried.

App.tsx

```
 <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Debug" component={A} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={B} />
            <Stack.Screen name="All" component={C} />
 </Stack.Navigator>
```

B.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            enableAudio();
        }

        if (isFocused === true) {
            console.log('play')
            playSound();
        } else if (isFocused === false) {
            console.log('stop')
            pauseSound();
        }

        return () => {
            pauseSound()
        }
    }, [isFocused]);

useEffect(() => {
        // ...
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
          console.log('blur');
          pauseSound();
        });
        return unsubscribe;
      }, []);

 const playSound = async () => {
        if (sound) {
            await sound.playAsync();
        }
        else {
            console.log('Loading Sound');
            const { sound } = await      Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('./../../assets/audio/001.ios.m4a'), { shouldPlay: true });
            setSound(sound)
            console.log('Playing Sound');
            await sound.playAsync();
        }

    }

    const pauseSound = async () => {
        if (sound) {
            console.log('Pausing Sound');
            await sound.pauseAsync();
        }
    }
return (
<View>
<Header/>
...
</View>
)
```

Header.tsx

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

return(
<View style={styles.container}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>
            <Image
               source={require('../../assets/icons/back_arrow.png')}
               style={{ height: 38, width: 19 }}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     ...
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a navigation event listener to your B component. The 'isFocused' state you're using doesn't always yield the desired result. You can try the following approach instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    console.log('focus');
    playSound();
  });

  const onBlur = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    console.log('blur');
    pauseSound();
  });

  return () => {
    onFocus();
    onBlur();
  };
}, []);
```